# How to change all associations in kde

Tags: kde, file-association

Gimp associated instead of Okular and gwienview to all mine graphical files and pdfs. There are so many options to change in file associations. Is there a way to do it quicker and better? In gnome I had just few options and I could do it in few clicks.